# Why string replace in JS doesn't replace all characters

Tags: javascript, string, replace, str-replace

```js
"-x-x+x".replace('-', '+')
```

equals

```js
"+x-x+x"
```

why isn't the second `-` replaced?

Comment: .replace only replace the first instance(character). to replace all instances you have to use regex.. console.log('-x-x+x'.replace(/-/g, '+'));

Comment: Searching StackOverflow for "[javascript] replace all instances" pulls up many duplicate posts asking essentially the same question.

Comment: @Taplar It doesn't answer _why_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.replace` only replaces the first instance it finds. To replace all of them, use a regex:

`"-x-x+x".replace(/-/g, '+')`

Note the `/g` at the end of the regex: it indicates "global" mode. Without it you'll still only replace the first instance.

Comment: Thanks for this, I was trying to find what the `/g` meant.

Answer (score 1):

Convert it to regex to replace all.

```js
console.log("-x-x+x".replace(/-/g, '+'))
```

Answer (score 1):

This is explained in the documentation for [`String#replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace):

[image]

Use a regular expression:

```js
'-x-x+x'.replace(/-/g, '+')
//=> "+x+x+x"
```